# Is formula $\mathtt{(∃x)(∀y)ϕ(x,y)}$ provable or refutable from $\mathtt{T}$ (in a Sound & Complete Proof System using the Axioms of $\mathtt{T}$)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, problem-solving, model-theory

Is the formula $\mathtt{(∃x)(∀y)ϕ(x, y)}$ provable or refutable from $\mathtt{T}$ (in a Sound and Complete Proof System using the Axioms of $\mathtt{T}$)

where
$$\mathtt{T} = \{\mathtt{(∀x)¬E(x, x), (∀x)(∀y)(E(x, y) → E(y, x)), (∀x)(∃y)ϕ(x, y)}\}$$
over the language $\mathtt{L}$ where $\mathtt{L}=\mathtt{(E)}$.
*$(\mathtt{E(x, y)}$ means in a graph that “the vertices $\mathtt{x}$ and $\mathtt{y}$ are adjacent” or “the vertices $\mathtt{x}$ and $\mathtt{y}$ are neighbors”$)$*

**Full Question**
[image: Full Question]

The reference for $Q2$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449055/find-a-model-and-a-non-model-of-a-theory-t-mathtt%E2%88%80x%C2%ACex-x-%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80yex). I am interested in Guidance for $Q3$.

Comment: If a theory proves a sentence, what do you know about all models of that theory?  If a theory refutes a sentence, what do you know about all models of that theory?

Answer (score 1):

Since the poof system is sound and complete,

> $\psi:=(\exists x)(\forall y) \varphi(x,y)$ is provable from $T$ iff every
> model $\mathcal{G}$ of $T$ satisfies $\psi$

Notice that a model of $T$ is neccesarily a graph (for the first two formulas involving $E$) which also satisfies that for all node $x$ in the graph there is a node $y$ in the graph such that $y$ has exactly two common neighbors with $x$.

So, the question is: Is true that a graph with all the previous properties satisfies that there is a node $z$ having exactly two common neighbors with all the nodes in the graph?

The answer is no because we can consider the graph $\Diamond=(V,E)$ where $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $E=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(1,4)\}$.

For $\neg\psi = (\forall x)(\exists y)\neg\varphi(x,y)$ you can check that the complete graph with $4$ vertices is a $T$-model where it doesn't hold $\neg\psi$.

Therefore, $\psi$ is neither provable or refutable from $T$.

Comment: Thank You. But you said there is 3 nodes in the model for T .  So Graph(V,E) where V={v1, v2,v3}and E={(v1,v2), (v2,v1),(v3,v1),(v3,v2) is this model correct?

Comment: I didn't say that there are only three nodes in a model for $T$. As you can see, $\Diamond$ is a model and it has 4 nodes.  Anyway, I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry but I meant for the second part of the question.

Comment: I don't know if this will clarify the argument, but every model of $T$ has at least $4$ elements. For a graph with three nodes, like a triangle, doesn't hold the property $(\forall x)(\exists y)\varphi(x,y)$ since every pair of nodes have only one common neighbor (the remainder node).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I understand it better now.